# Derived functor vs. spectral sequence

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra, spectral-sequences

I heard many times that because of introducing derived category, we can avoid cumbersome spectral sequence. However, I don't quite understand its meaning. Here is a precise example people talking about:

Let $f: X \to Y, g: Y \to Z$ be morphism of smooth varieties, and Let $D(X), D(Y), D(Z)$ be derived category of bounded complexes of quasi-coherent sheaves. Then it is said that because of the associativity of derived functor, i.e.

$${\rm{R}}f_* \circ {\rm{R}}g_* = {\rm{R}}{(f \circ g)}_*\quad,$$

we can avoid the write the spectral sequence.

I don't know which spectral sequence people refer to, and why the associativity of derived functor equivalent to that spectral sequence?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The spectral sequence is the Leray spectral sequence
$$E_2^{i,j} :=  R^if_* R^jg_* \mathcal F\implies R^{i+j}(f\circ g)_*\mathcal F.$$

Comment: Ahaaa, I see, thank you very much! Besides, should that spectral sequence be called Grothendieck spectral sequence?

Comment: @LiYutong: Dear Li Yutong, Maybe.  (If $f$ is the map to a point, then it is the Leray spectral sequence.)  Regards,

Comment: Dear Matt, another thing I forgot to ask is how can we use the associativity of derived functor to get this spectral sequence (i.e. without using spectral sequence associated to the double complex)?

Comment: Dear Li Yutong, You do have to use the spectral sequence associated to a double complex.  (Maybe there is another way, but the spectral sequence of a double complex is what I would use.)  At least for me, the point is that the language of derived categories allows us to talk about $Rf_*$, $Rg_*$, etc., without having to unpack everything in terms of complexes, double complexes, and spectral sequences.  Regards,